# Why some of my LVM filesystems use /dev/dm paths instead of /dev/mapper/ paths in df output?

Tags: lvm, disk-usage

All my filesystems are hosted by LVM logical volumes :

```bash
$ lsblk -l | grep lvm
vids_VG-iso (dm-11)         252:11   0    32G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm  
KUbuntu_VG-usr (dm-1)       252:1    0    22G  0 lvm  /usr
KUbuntu_VG-var (dm-2)       252:2    0    10G  0 lvm  /var
KUbuntu_VG-boot (dm-3)      252:3    0     5G  0 lvm  /boot
KUbuntu_VG-usr_local (dm-4) 252:4    0     8G  0 lvm  
KUbuntu_VG-opt (dm-5)       252:5    0     5G  0 lvm  
KUbuntu_VG-tmp (dm-6)       252:6    0    17G  0 lvm  /tmp
KUbuntu_VG-swap (dm-7)      252:7    0    12G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
KUbuntu_VG-rootFS (dm-8)    252:8    0    10G  0 lvm  /
KUbuntu_VG-var_cache (dm-9) 252:9    0    10G  0 lvm  
KUbuntu_VG-var_tmp (dm-10)  252:10   0     1G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
home_VG-home (dm-0)         252:0    0   100G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-iso (dm-11)         252:11   0    32G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm  
vids_VG-vids (dm-12)        252:12   0 586,6G  0 lvm
```

Why, then, some of my filesystems use `/dev/dm-` paths instead of `/dev/mapper/` paths in `df` output :

```bash
$ df -PTh | egrep -v "squashfs|vfat" | grep /dev/
/dev/dm-8                      ext4      9,8G  1,5G  7,8G  16% /
/dev/dm-12                     btrfs     587G  586G   53M 100% /datas
/dev/dm-0                      btrfs     100G   99G  228M 100% /home
/dev/dm-11                     btrfs      32G   30G  249M 100% /iso
/dev/dm-5                      btrfs     5,0G  3,0G  1,8G  64% /opt
/dev/mapper/KUbuntu_VG-usr     ext4       22G   15G  5,6G  73% /usr
/dev/mapper/KUbuntu_VG-var     ext4      9,8G  1,6G  7,7G  17% /var
/dev/mapper/KUbuntu_VG-boot    ext4      4,8G  185M  4,4G   4% /boot
/dev/mapper/KUbuntu_VG-tmp     ext4       17G  2,4G   14G  15% /tmp
/dev/dm-4                      btrfs     8,0G  4,4G  3,4G  57% /usr/local
/dev/mapper/KUbuntu_VG-var_tmp ext4      976M  180M  729M  20% /var/tmp
```

Comment: Can you show your `fstab`? Mounting via path is slightly different to mounting via UUID.

Comment: @KenSharp I don't have this system anymore. But as far as I remember, I edited my `fstab` so as to replace `UUID`s by `/dev/VGName/LVName` paths.

Answer (score 0):

Those are LVM logical "devices" part of the device mapper in the kernel, used by LVM. `dmsetup ls`

& mapper path devices are logical volumes 
This is just 2 different things.

Comment: I don't understand your answer for my setup, because all my filesystems are hosted on LVM LVs. I just updated my question with some more details, can you please have a look ?

Comment: LVM use both devices (dm-x) or volume (with maper)   BUT from functional point of view they are same..  UDEV for example would use /dev/dm-x User would use the mapper type ... in facts access methods are tow differents things but on functionnal point of view it is the same

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific in your answer and tell WHEN `/dev/dm-x` paths are used and WHEN `/dev/mapper/xyzt....` paths are used ?

Comment: udev or any other system process creating it = dmx   vs user or bashscript  command create it = mapper for the volume

Comment: Maybe, my question was a little confusing, I'm not trying to find out WHO (what process) created `/dev/dm-x` and `/dev/mapper/xyzt....` paths.  I'm, rather, trying to know : WHAT condition(s) on the LVs, the `/dev/dm-x` paths are created  over `/dev/mapper/xyzt....` paths ?

Answer (score 0):

`df` output length limit，exceeds and has soft link will output `dm-xx`:

```shellsession
[root@ ~]# lvcreate -n lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e2 -V 10Mi  --thinpool testmysql/mysqlpool0
[root@ ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/testmysql/lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e2
[root@ ~]# mount  /dev/testmysql/lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e2 /mnt/
[root@ ~]# df -h |grep mnt
/dev/mapper/testmysql-lvm--05d5eb5b--a248--4904--aa6f--0f3e2                                                                         11M  204K  9.6M   3% /mnt
```

add 2

```shellsession
[root@ ~]# lvcreate -n lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e22 -V 10Mi  --thinpool testmysql/mysqlpool0
[root@ ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/testmysql/lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e22
[root@ ~]# mount  /dev/testmysql/lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e22 /mnt/
[root@ ~]# df -h |grep mnt
/dev/dm-252                                                                                                                          11M  204K  9.6M   3% /mnt

[root@ ~]# ls /dev/testmysql/lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e22  -lrt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 12 17:23 /dev/testmysql/lvm-05d5eb5b-a248-4904-aa6f-0f3e22 -> ../dm-252
```

Comment: You know you can run e.g. `df -h /mnt` to restrict the output of `df` to the filesystem of that particular directory, right?

Comment: This doesn't tally up with the output though: all the mounts are different sizes.